# How to convert a list to a data.frame in R

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I want to convert a list to a data frame in R.

My list:

```
myList <- list(
`JJ-NN-NN` = c("hybridized","cmp","conditioner"),
`JJ-JJ-NN` = c("first", "abrasive", "unit"))

> myList
$`JJ-NN-NN`
[1] "hybridized"  "cmp"         "conditioner"
$`JJ-JJ-NN`
[1] "first"    "abrasive" "unit"
```

I want to get this data frame.

```
    POS          Word
1   JJ-NN-NN     hybridized cmp conditioner
2   JJ-JJ-NN     first abrasive unit
```

Answer (score 12):

please try the code below:

```
   a=do.call(rbind,lapply(myList,paste0,collapse=" "))
    data.frame(pos=rownames(a),word=a,row.names = NULL)
```

If this helps please let us know. Thank you

EDIT:

```
aggregate(.~ind,stack(myList),paste,collapse=' ')
       ind                     values
1 JJ-NN-NN hybridized cmp conditioner
2 JJ-JJ-NN        first abrasive unit
```

Comment: Am glad it was of help. please see 
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) for more instructions on what to do when the solution is correct

Comment: and riffing off Onyambu's answer `stack(lapply(myList,paste0,collapse=" "))`

Answer (score 2):

Here is another solution that stays within the `tidyverse`.

```
library(tidyverse)
map(myList, paste0, collapse = " ") %>% bind_rows() %>% gather(POS, Word)
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe more straightforward:

```
data.frame(POS = names(myList),Word = sapply(myList,paste,collapse=" "),row.names = seq_along(myList))
```

Answer (score 0):

****Hello all*;***

This can be helpful

```
myList<- myData

myData<-data.frame(myData)
```

If you want to stack your variables for ANOVA purpose then use this

```
myData<-stack(myData)
```

Hope it works